# Defining a route in Symfony 2 with variable action

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Just imagine, I have a controller with several actions in it. 
And to reach each action I have to define it strictly in routing.yml file like this:

```
admin_edit_routes:
    pattern:  /administrator/edituser
    defaults: { _controller: MyAdminBundle:Default:edituser }
admin_add_routes:
    pattern:  /administrator/adduser
    defaults: { _controller: MyAdminBundle:Default:adduser }
```

And I can have plenty of such pages. What I want to achieve is to define necessary action in my URI, just like Kohana routes do.
I mean, I want simply to use one route for all actions:
(code below is not valid, just for example)

```
admin_main_route:
    pattern:  /administrator/{action}
    defaults: { _controller: MyAdminBundle:Default:{action} action:index}
```

It will pass all requests to /administrator/{anything} to this route, and after that, according to the action, stated in the uri, the needed action is gonna to be called.
If action is not stated in the uri, then we got thrown to index action.

Is it possible in Symfony 2 in any ways and if yes, then how?
Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't feel right to do so. By exposing your controller API (methods) *"on the fly"* directly via GET method, you open your application to security vulnerabilities. This can also easily lead to unwanted behaviours.
Moreover, how would you generate routes in twig for example ? By giving explicit constants tied to the method names?

```
{{ path('dynamic_route', { 'method': 'addUser' }) }}
```

This is not how Symfony works nor what it recommands. Symfony is not CodeIgniter nor Kohana. You don't need a second *"Front Controller"*

If this is a laziness matter, you can switch your routing configurations to [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html). And let Symfony auto-generate the routes you need, with minimal efforts.

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/administrator")
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request);

    /**
     * @Route("/adduser")
     */
    public function addUserAction(Request $request);

    /**
     * @Route("/edituser")
     */
    public function editUserAction(Request $request);

    /**
     * @Route("/{tried}")
     */
    public function fallbackAction($tried, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->indexAction($request);
    }
}
```

The `fallbackAction` methods, returns any `/administrator/*` route which does not exist to the `indexAction` content.

To sum up, I advise not to use dynamic routing *"on the fly"* directly to method names.
An alternative would be to create a command which will generate routes once executed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe that's not the best way to do that, but it works. Your `dynamicAction` accepts `action` string parameter and checks if such action exists. If so, it executes given action with `params`.

```
/**
 * Default Controller.
 *
 * @Route("/default")
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/{action}/{params}", name="default_dynamic")
     */
    public function dynamicAction($action, $params = null)
    {
        $action = $action . 'Action';
        if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
            return $this->{$action}($params);
        }

        return $this->indexAction();
    }
}
```

I'm curious if someone have any other ideas :>

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've also had similar idea, but still seeking for alternative variants :)